# Where can i find detailed dimensions of an aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design

I am doing a University project that analyses an aircraft aerodynamics. And to do that i need to replicate an aircraft in AutoCAD, then do a simulation.

Is there a public source where i can find the specific dimensions of an aircraft(nothing specific)?

I'm grateful for any insights you can provide on this, and thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: An airplane is much more than its length, weight, and wingspan.  How deep will the analysis be?  Will you need moments of inertia, airfoil names, wing stiffness, control surface deflections, attributes of the turbine or piston engine or propellor(s)?

Comment: Currently i am concerned only with the physical dimensions, that include the airfoil name, whatever help me design the body of the aircraft

Comment: Resource location questions are not on-topic on this forum.

Comment: Length is easy to find. Contour, slope etc are harder. How detailed you need?

Comment: "*where i can find the specific dimensions of an aircraft (nothing specific)?*  Well, that clears it right up...

Comment: If this is ignoring aerodynamics, only about reconstructing the shape of an airplane from drawings and numbers, then this question might be better for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/3d-modelling.  Googling for "3 view" finds many drawings, e.g. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:3-view_orthographic_projections_of_aircraft.

Answer (score 3):

Do a Google Image search for the name of the aircraft with "3 view drawing" in the search field.

Also, consult [The Incomplete Guide To Airfoil Usage](https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/aircraft.html) to possibly get a clue to the airfoil used.

Beyond that, consult "Janes All the World's Aircraft" -- your University library should have a copy.  The library is the old building nobody uses with all the books in it.

Comment: +1 just because the last sentence made me laugh!

Answer (score 0):

Exactly how detailed do you need?  Basic information can be obtained from a manufacturers database. More detailed information may be found in an aircraft flight manual or aircraft maintenance manuals.  Some manufacturers offer quick reference guides and product review sheets, which contains specifications. This products are typically only available to serious buyers; not typically public available from a website or anything.